# Content type of clustering in sql 2012

Tags: ssas, cluster-analysis, data-mining, ssas-2012

Is it possible to change the data state in clustering using SQL server 2012? I clustered data using SQL server 2012 but state of data of each attribute is not real I select content type of input data Continuous but in this type range of data is very large and when I select another type it don't show real data of each cluster with drill through. Is there any way for solved the problem of range data in clustering?

Comment: Can you rephrase this? I'm not sure what you're asking - maybe include some example code?

Comment: I want sample cluster data for large data set  in SQL and I have problem in clustering large data set with SQL that data of each cluster isn't real data.

Comment: What does large mean to you? For example, you can start with the Stack Overflow Creative Commons data dump that has tens of millions of rows, and fits in ~75GB of space.

Comment: the mean of large data is large data of each tuple is big, I don't know exactly what is my problem? but I when clustered my data and select content type for each input the state of shading value isn't true and real data, I want to show real state for each shading value that to know which range of data there is in  each cluster

Comment: Ahhh, you're using SQL Server Analysis Services. This is a different product than SQL Server - it technically comes "free in the box" with SQL Server, but it's a completely different product with its own experts. Retagging this to get you better help.